# Web-app version is overridden when launching Tomcat 7 from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, version, overriding

I'm developping a web application that is using web-fragment.xml files.

AFAIK, the web-framgent.xml files of the JAR in WEB-INF/lib should be merged and resolved to an effective web.xml.
So, I activate the logEffectiveWebXml option of my Tomcat 7 server to see the resulting file.

Hereby the beginning of the effective web.xml file:

Case 1: When the application is deploy on a standalone Tomcat 7:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0"
         metadata-complete="true">
```

Case 2: When the application is deploy on a Tomcat 7 in Eclipse IDE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         metadata-complete="true">
```

You notice that the version attribute is replaced with "2.5".

Besides, the effective web.xml is correct when deploying the app on the standalone Tomcat (the content of web-fragments.xml files are merged) whereas these contents are absent when launching Tomcat from Eclipse.
I think this is due to the version override.

**Do you know why the version attribute is overriden when launching in Eclipse?**

I inspect Eclipse configuration, projects configuration (they all use dynamic web module 3.0) and workspace directory ".metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core" but I don't manage to find something wrong...

NOTE: I also notice that the version is overridden even if I don't deploy my application (= fresh Tomcat install).

Thanks for your help.